# Updating Rails view from JS using remote = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in a Rails view:

(a little simplified to fit in a question)

```
<%= link_to "FAV", :action => 'make_fav', 
    remote: true,  data: {old_state: "NOTFAV", 
    product: product.id} %>
```

which works and calls a method "make_fav" in my controller. This methods updates the database and sets an instance variable @newstate = "FAV"

in make_fav.js.erb I can see that this instance variable is set

```
<% puts "Newstate is #{@newstate}" %>
```

in my index.html.erb, I have

```
<td id='<%= "favourite-#{product.id}" %>' >
  <% if current_user.products.exists?(product.id) %>
      <i class="fa fa-star" %></i>
  <% else %>
      <i class="fa fa-star-o" %></i>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Now how should I (in make_fav.js.erb) update the td with id "favourite-#{product.id}" to reflect the @newstate variable?

I have tried things like

```
<% @key = "#favourite-#{@product.id}" %> 
<% x = "<i class='fa fa-star' id='favourite-#{@product.id}></i>" %>

$('<%= @key %>').html("<%= escape_javascript (x) %>");
```

but as you can see, I'm at a loss when it comes to javascript...

Basically, I want to update the  content to

```
<i class="fa fa-star" %></i>
```

if @newstate is "FAV", and else

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o" %></i>
```

I feel like I'm close, but would appreciate any help!

Also, if there is a better/more "railsy" way of doing it, I would like to hear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is not too far from the solution. It seems like you are correctly calculating the `id` of the element you want to find, but you want to update the `i` element within that ID. So a small change on your `make_fav.js.erb` could do the trick. Try changing to:

```
(function() {
  var id = "#favourite-<%= @product.id %> i";
  if ($(id).hasClass('fa-star-o')) {
    $(id).addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
  } else {
    $(id).addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
  }
})();
```

In this solution, we first define the selector of the `i` you want to find (which is the `i` within the `favourite-id` and swap the class (if it was `fa-star` it goes to `fa-star-o` and vice versa).

Note that instead of using `$(id).hasClass('fa-star-o')` in that condition, you should use the new state of the data (I just didn't know how it'd look like your particular case), but the `make_fav.js.erb` could look like:

```
(function() {
  var id = "#favourite-<%= @product.id %> i";
  <% if current_user.products.exists?(product.id) %>
    $(id).addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
  <% else %>
    $(id).addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
  <% end %>
})();
```

That would be the preferred way, because you're not relying on the state of UI, but on the state of the data.

Comment: Thanks! My inexperience with js/jquery had me forget the addClass/removeClass angle!

Comment: And, to be specific, in the index.html.erb, I have a loop over products, and set class depending on "current_user.products.exists?(product.id)", but I do that in ruby code, and not JS. To avoid duplication, is there any way I could use the same code for initial update (which is server rendered in ruby now) and the JS callback code in the client? I was thinking to write a JS function that could be used by both, but it somehow feels like I'm overworking it then...